# Strategy to introduce CQRS in classic CRUD system

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm looking for a way to migrate to a CQRS driven architecture from an already running anaemic model/Transaction Script'ish system. I was thinking of making the current state a (handcrafted) Snapshot from where Event Sourcing will pick up further changes. Would this be a proper way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is one way to do it.  We used a special `XXXImported` event with the current state to make the import event explicit (even though `XXXImported` is clearly not part of the domain language).

We found it's a good idea to do the conversion gradually, and start with those use cases where you can see benefits of using CQRS+ES, i.e., where you can get actual performance gains, can achieve looser coupling or where you can benefit from explicit event history.  Trivial use cases, or cases where performance doesn't matter, can be converted later.

Comment: Thanks! So you created a XXXImported event for each item in the CRUD-DB where XXX is the AggregateRoot?

Comment: Yes, that's what we did.